# How to Implement SSO using Django and React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, single-sign-on

I wanted to achieve Single Sign-On similar to Google, Youtube, Gmail, Drive where only you have to sign in only one time for all the apps.

My application backend is on Django Rest Framework - Using JWT Token
Front-end: I have two different React apps hosted on two different domains.

I read that, google used cookies for the SSO but I haven't found any practical example on how to achieve it.

Comment: All of the Google services with "implied" single sign-on are hosted under *.google.com, so they can use a single cookie set on google.com. For youtube, you do log in separately.

Comment: In my case, all app is hosted as a sub-domain under a single domain. And NO - you don't have to log in separately for youtube - I have checked it.